# PdfClown TextMarkUp Color change

Tags: java, colors, background-color, highlight, pdfclown

I am doing a search in PDF and if found hightlight it, so created a TextMarkup object with MarkupTypeEnum.Highlight, and tried to change the color as

```
textMarkup.setColor(DeviceRGBColor.get(Color.RED));  or
textMarkup.setColor(new DeviceRGBColor((35.0/255.0), (35.0/255.0), (142.0/255.0)))
```

still the highlights are shown in yellow (default). its not changing the color as i requested. Please let me know, if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appearance refresh on text-markup color change was recently fixed: please [download the latest revision](http://pdfclown.org/downloads/) (get the "bugfix snapshot" if you are using PDF Clown 0.1.2 or earlier).